# __PHP_Incomplete_Class even though class is loaded

Tags: php, serialization, magento2, php-7.4

I'm trying to cache a SOAP response (a class object with multiple child objects).

Let's say my response object is `$responseObject` and I save it to a file called `/tmp/response.dat` with `$this->io->save(serialize($responseObject), '/tmp/response.dat');` (pseudo code).

When trying to get that response later (in a new request) via `$responseObject = unserialize($this->io->read('/tmp/response.dat'));` I get a `__PHP_Incomplete_Class` even though the needed classes are autoloaded (I'm using Magento and therefor it is automatically autoloaded long before trying to read the object from the file), I even tried to iterate through the SOAP classes folder and `require()`d all of them to be 100% sure all of the classes get included.

A `$responseObject = unserialize(serialize($responseObject));` works perfectly, also reading from the saved file and unserializing that string works if the SOAP call actually got executed right before, and the serialized strings in the file and right after the call are exact the same - it just does not work when only trying to unserialize from the file, even though I tested to iteratively include all possible classes (and an autoloader IS present).

Can anybody tell me what's the issue here?

Answer (score 0):

PHP serializes its sessions using the built-in serialize and unserialize methods. serialize of PHP has the ability to serialize PHP objects (aka class instances) and convert them to string. When you unserialize those strings, It converts them back to those same classes with those values. Classes who have some private properties and want to encode/decode that or do something complex in their serialization/deserialization implement the Serializable class and add serialize and unserialize methods to the class.

When PHP's unserialize tries to unserialize a class object, but the class name isn't declared/required, instead of giving a warning or throwing an Exception, it converts it to an object of __PHP_Incomplete_Class.

If you don't want your session objects to convert to __PHP_Incomplete_Class, You can do it by either requiring the class files before you invoke session_start, or by registering an autoload function.

Comment: Hi and thanks for your answer. My question has nothing to do with sessions, and the classes are required and declared at the time of unserialize(). I unfortunately found no way to fix this issue.